# Sequence of numbers classifying

Tags: python

Are there any better solutions than comparing the current number with the previous or the upcoming one in order to classify the same numbers?

e.g. if I have a sequence of numbers like:`[1.123,1.123,1.223,1.123,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.1,4.011,4.001,4.011,4.1011]`

I do want to know identify all the same floats (no matter if it's +-1 e.g 1 is 1 no matter if it's 1.123 or 1.223)

As long as I classify the beginnign and the end of the same ones (A= 1,1,1,1) (B= 2,2,2,2) (C= 4,4,4,4)

quasi code/idea:

```
x = [1.123,1.123,1.223,1.123,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.1,4.011,4.001,4.011,4.1011]
x.append(float('-inf'))


    for i in range(1, len(x) - 1, 1): 
        if (x[i] > x[i - 1] and 
            x[i] > x[i + 1]): 
            print('msg')
```

Is there any easier way to identify them other than doing it under a condition like this? is there any way to use the `while` loop maybe?

Something like this?! :

```
x = [1.123,1.123,1.223,1.123,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.1,4.011,4.001,4.011,4.1011]
A =[] #all with 1.123,1.123,1.223,1.123
B = [] #all 2.1,2.1,2.2,2.1
C = [] #4.011,4.001,4.011,4.1011
count=0

while same_numbers_plusmin_1 is True:
           if count == 0:
               for i in x:
                    A.append(i)
                    print('classified first sequence of numbers, with range of 1to2 difference')
           if count == 1:
                    B.append(i)
                    print('classified second sequence of numbers, with range of 1to2 difference')
           if count == 2:
                    C.append(i)
                    print('classified third sequence of numbers, with range of 1to2 difference')
 
else:
     count+=1
     print('new sequence of same numbers, added to new list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [1.123,1.123,1.223,1.123,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.1,4.011,4.001,4.011,4.1011]

groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(x, key=int)]
# [[1.123, 1.123, 1.223, 1.123], [2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1], [4.011, 4.001, 4.011, 4.1011]]

# or if you want them converted
groups = [[k for _ in g] for k, g in groupby(x, key=int)]
# [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4, 4]]

count = len(groups)
```

Now, for most intents I can think of, having a list of groups should be prefered over some independently named variables that you could still extract:

```
A, B, C, *_ = groups
```

But the most useful data structure would be a dictionary mapping classification key to data:

```
groups = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(x, key=int)}
# {1: [1.123, 1.123, 1.223, 1.123], 
#  2: [2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1], 
#  4: [4.011, 4.001, 4.011, 4.1011]}
```

Comment: seems to work with the afromentioned example. However, if it's one unit higher or lower it doesn't group it. Meaning that in my case just drastical unit osciallations shouldn't be grouped, while everything else should correspond to the same gorup e.g. this is my grouping which is wrong because 148 should still be among 147
  [147.83999633789062,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812],
 [148.07998657226562],
 [147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812,
  147.95999145507812],